# How do you output file size of multiple files in a directory using bash?

Tags: linux, shell

The file extension is .yuv 
There are multiple files with different extensions stored in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

Use globbing with `du` to get the filesystem block based size:

```
du -sh *.yuv
```

`ls` to get the actual file size:

```
ls -l *.yuv
```